# Objective-C = operator vs stringWithString/arrayWithArray

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to obj-c development but partly have background in C development. It might be a noob question but I couldn't get an exact answer in other places. What is the difference between these snippets for arrays and strings and possibly other types of objects:

```
NSArray *original = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:someObjects,nil];
//Case 1
NSArray *copy1 = original;
//Case 2
NSArray *copy2 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:original];
```

and for strings

```
NSString *original = @"aString";
//Case 1
NSString *copy1 = original;
//Case 2
NSString *copy2 = [NSString stringWithString:original];
```

If I make changes to copy1 and copy2 later will they be reflected on original objects? And does the same rules apply to other object types?

Comment: Both `NSArray` and `NSString` are bad examples to understand basic pointer semantics and object identity as they are optimized **not to create copies** if the original cannot be changed (is immutable).

Comment: You can't make changes to the strings pointed to by ether copy1 or copy2; they're immutable. But you may assign new values to copy1 or copy2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really about what objects pointers are pointing to. When you say `make changes to copy1 and copy2 later`, I guess you mean to the pointer contents, not to the object referenced by that pointer. This is a rather functional way to think, but it important non-the-less.

In your example, the array / string part doesn't matter, because you aren't doing anything with the objects, you are just doing things with the pointers to those objects.

`original` points to one object. `copy1` points to the same object. `copy2` points to a different object (but which, in this case, is a copy of the first object).

Comment: Since the original is an immutable string copy2 is not a different object but the exact same instance.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, in this case, yes, but I felt that complicated the topic. I could expand and consider mutable objects if it would help

Answer (score 3):

The second code snippet does for `NSString` what the first code snippet does for `NSArray`. There is no difference in the behavior, because both `NSString` and `NSArray` objects in Cocoa are *immutable*.

When you call `[NSString stringWithString:original]`, Cocoa is smart enough not to create a new object: the reasoning behind this decision is that since `original` cannot be changed, there's nothing you could do to tell apart a copy from the original. Same goes for `[NSArray arrayWithArray:original]`, because you get the same instance back.

Note: If `someObjects` is mutable, one could tell apart an array from its deep copy by modifying the object, and seeing if it changes in the other place. However, `arrayWithArray:` method makes a "shallow" copy, so you wouldn't be able to detect a difference even if the objects inside your array are mutable.

Comment: `someObjects` mutability is irrelevant for `arrayWithArray` creating a new instance or not. Only the receiver is considered. Copies are always shallow.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe My point was that if the object is mutable, you can tell if a deep copy has been made or not. If it is immutable, there's no legal way to tell them apart.

Comment: Both arrays (the original and the one returned from `arrayWithArray`) can never be told apart because they are the same instance (if, as in this case the original is immutable). This does not depend on the elements.

Comment: I think, now  I get what you meant in the first place. I was confused by the deep vs. shallow copy (because Cocoa just knows shallow copies) and the problem was shallow vs. no copy at all. Alas, I can up-vote only once :(

Answer (score 2):

`copy1` is not a copy, but another pointer to the same memory as `original`. `copy2` is actually a copy, pointing at a different piece of memory.

If you modify `copy1` (assuming it was mutable, which you example code is not), you are modifying `original` too, as they point at the same piece of memory.

If you modify `copy2`, `original` should be unchanged (generally speaking). In your array example, the objects in the array `original` and in the array `copy2` are, I believe the same. So you in this case, you have *two* arrays, but they have in them the same objects.

Comment: `copy2` is not pointing to a different piece of memory. It's the same instance.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Sorry, no. `+arrayWithArray` returns a new array, populated with the contents of it's argument. A quick test bore this out as well.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong. I was under the impression `arrayWithArray:` would do the same optimization as `copy`. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

NSArrays and NSStrings are immutable so you can't change them.

You can't add or remove objects from NSArray, but if you change some object in array, it will change in its copy because NSArray holds a pointer to it.